# What is the status of the F-1B engine development?

Tags: engines, sls

In this article https://arstechnica.com/science/2013/04/new-f-1b-rocket-engine-upgrades-apollo-era-deisgn-with-1-8m-lbs-of-thrust/ and in several answers on this site a modernized F-1 engine is referred as being planned to be used on the SLS.

What is the status on that, is that still in the plan and if so how is schedule and progress looking?

**Edit**
Questions that prompted this:

- [Why design new rocket engines instead of using the existing types?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/11976/why-design-new-rocket-engines-instead-of-using-the-existing-types/11977#11977)
- [Why were Solid Rockets chosen for the SLS](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13986/why-were-solid-rockets-chosen-for-the-sls/14056#14056)

Comment: it would be great if you could add links to the "several answers on this site" so other readers could see what you're referring to. That's better than everyone having to do their own search for them. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That project has been cancelled (or at least put on hold) as of June 2019.

> But NASA discontinued studies of upgrading the SLS, including study of
>   reviving the F-1. Soon the testing of the F-1 gas generator at
>   Marshall Space Flight Center also came to a halt. The F-1 went silent
>   once more.

This [article](http://www.thespacereview.com/article/3724/1) in The Space Review has a good summary of the effort to bring it back and what happened.

Comment: That is a great article!